# To-Do-List Planner with sub-tasks

Tags: gratis, task-management, planning

I am looking for a To-Do-List-Planer for my Laptop, so either a Desktop software or an online-software is what I'm looking for.

I've seen this things built in digital company infrastructure.

It's a to-Do-List with multiple columns, e.g. Private, Project 1, Project 2, Work 1, Work 2 etc.
In each column you can create cards with your to-do-stuff but you can also create sub-tasks for a bigger task. E.g. if I have to do a big redesign for my company I would like to structure it in smaller tasks e.g. website, magazine, logo etc. with sub-tasks.

Most of the times you can also drag and drop cards from one column to another.

Anyway, I couldn't find any online planner that lets me create subtasks, and of course time it, which is also free.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Teamhood Kanban](https://teamhood.com/use-cases/task-management) as it is flexible Kanban board which covers your mentioned backlog, task list, subtasks and few other points on top. Plus it is **free**!

**Kanban View:**
[image: Teamhood Kanban]

**List View:**
[image]

[Teamhood](https://teamhood.com)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview of the popular [free kanban tools](https://teamhood.com/kanban/free-kanban-software/). Complete with a comparison of their features side by side.
Hope it helps, since finding the right tool comes to personal preference as much as a list of features.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65624)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Todo lists are for more simpler stuff.

What you need is something easier and that can manage task, sub tasks, etc

there is a project/tasks management tool called  [Asana](https://asana.com/pricing)

Its basically a huge tool with a lot of features.

what it favors you is its free for basic usage, which will be enough in your case.

It allows you to create

- unlimited tasks list, with simple inline input, file attachment, and checkmark to complete
- unlimited subtasks within a task and with individual due dates and checks
- Kanban board, which in your case is for project 1, project 2, Private, Work 1, and can drag and drop task between columns
- milestones to track progress
- Assign team mates to tasks
- Free trial for up to 15 users.
- Real-time commenting on tasks
- inbox for updates

with quite friendly and easy User interface and easier for everyone

also android and IOS app is available

[image: view]
[image: kanban board]

Answer (score 0):

Also [height.app](https://height.app/) can be a neat solution for you.

Not only **kanban** board is suported, also **chat** in context, **calendar**, **tasks** and many features, with a very cool handling and great usability and moreover there is a **free** plan with **unlimited** members and taks.

[image]